# Module compiled with Swift 4.0.3 cannot be imported in Swift 4.1

Tags: swift, frameworks, swift4, swift4.1

I'm trying to import a framework in app, after to update Xcode to version 9.3 that supports swift 4.1. When I import it, appears this error:

**Module compiled with Swift 4.0.3 cannot be imported in Swift 4.1: /Users/mgutierrezd/Desktop/Lapso/FrameworkAsesorEnLinea.framework/Modules/FrameworkAsesorEnLinea.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftmodule**

I Tried to delete derived data, but it doesn't work.

Comment: The "module" needs to be rebuilt using Xcode 9.3/Swift 4.1 - are you using Pods or Carthage or is it a custom or third part library

Comment: This is because Swift does not have [module stability](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution) yet and there's a high chance that it WILL NOT come in Swift 5 either. You will have to recompile your framework in Swift 4.1

Comment: I'm using Pods inside my framework.

Comment: Were you able to fix this @MateoGutierrezDiaz ? I am running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

When compiling an application using Swift 4.1, your frameworks need to be compiled using Swift 4.1 as well. Recompile your frameworks and you will solve this problem.